# For which pairs of distinct positive primes $p$ and $q$, the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{pq}]$ is a UFD?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

For which pairs of distinct positive primes $p$ and $q$, the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{pq}]$ is a UFD? I've proved that neither $p$ nor $q$ can be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: And the only possible case I knew is that $p=2$ and $q=3$.

Comment: You expect an explicit description? That is hopeless. There are more, probably infinitely many, but it's not realistic at present to expect a list. Other examples include $pq$ equal to 14, 21, 22, 33, 46, 57, 62, 69, and 77.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit surprised. Do you know if the converse holds? That is when $p$, $q$ are disticnt positive primes, $q\equiv 3\pmod 4$, $p=2$ or $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{pq}]$ must be UFD?

Comment: The converse surely does not hold, I believe. Being a UFD in this context is equivalent to having class number 1, and that is quite a difficult problem to address.

Comment: The converse doesn't hold, and as Greg briefly put it you really shouldn't expect any simple rule predicting an infinite list of real quadratic fields with class number $1$. Examples where the converse does not hold include $pq$ equal to $142$, $254$, $321$, $326$, $469$, $473$, $817$, $1957$, and $2021$. In these cases the class number is $3$ except for $817$, where the class number is $5$.

Comment: Well, it seems that I didn't realize how complicated the question is. Thanks a lot.